# Why my uSec delay with SysTick STM32f429i_Discovery doesn`t work?

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

[A rubbish value assigned to the Interrupt variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTVBr.png)

I am trying to create a delay function using SysTick counter.

I am using my own functions:

```
SysTick_Init(uint32_t ticks);
```

this function takes a parameter that represents the interval that interrupts should be triggered, so if I want to trigger an interrupt each 1mS then

```
SysTick_Init(SystemCoreClock/1000);
```

I did successfully create a delay with 1 mSec without using the delay_uS function I used the delay_MS function directly that was my first trial. The problem is when I try to create a delay with 1uSec.

I have a Global variable called `Micro`, this variable is initialized with a value passed to function `delay_ms(some variable)`. Then function `delay_ms` calls function delay_uS. The implementation is in the image above.

So when I initialize Micro with 1000000 and the interrupt is triggered every 1 uSec, I can create a delay with 1 sec.
Micro is initialized with a very random value as stated in the first picture.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this problem?

Comment: did you declare Micro as volatile?  systick only has a 24 bit counter, didnt dig into this library to see if you are limited to that or if the library looks at that.

Comment: You _talk_ about the code without actually _presenting_ the code.  The image shows only part if the code you discuss.

Comment: Post real code instead of picture please. Where does your "Micro" variable is declared and initialized ? If you use HAL which seems to be the case, be aware that systick is programmed at HAL inits to fire irq every milliseconds so counting uS without modify reaload register will not work. Also `while(Micre >0);` is not a good practice since it's really power consuming for the chip. You might want to use a low power mode like sleep mode.

Comment: Most of the time, wait-busy loops fail because you didn't declare the loop iterator as `volatile`. The solution is most often to avoid such loops though, because they rarely make sense outside very simplistic systems.

Comment: You can use the HAL_SYSTICK_Callback(). This function is declared __weak in HAL_SYSTICK_IRQ_Handler(void)

If you want delay_uS(), use the   SysTick->VAL and SysTick->LOAD. SysTick->LOAD holds the uC (SystemCoreClock/1000) and SysTick->VAL goes from LOAD to 0 the reload. If your uC clock is at 72mHz, 1uS is 72 ticks from SysTick->VAL.